# How do you prove this problem?

Tags: pythagorean-triples

Suppose (a,b,c) is a primitive Pythagorean Triple. Prove that c cannot be a multiple of 3.

Comment: What are your thoughts? What have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

Wlog suppose that $a^2+b^2=c^2$. We only need to work$\mod 3$. Since your hypothesis is that $(a,b,c)$ is a primitive pythagorean triple, then $a$ and $b$ are coprime. So by symmetry these are the cases:

i) $a\equiv 0 \pmod 3$ and $b\equiv 1 \pmod 3$

ii) $a\equiv 0 \pmod 3$ and $b\equiv 2 \pmod 3$

iii) $a\equiv 1 \pmod 3$ and $b\equiv 1 \pmod 3$

iv) $a\equiv 1 \pmod 3$ and $b\equiv 2 \pmod 3$

v) $a\equiv 2 \pmod 3$ and $b\equiv 2 \pmod 3$

Take for example case ii). We have $a^2+b^2\equiv 1 \pmod 3$, then $c^2\equiv 1 \pmod 3$ and therefore $c$ isn't multiple of $3$. The other cases are analogous.

Comment: I assumed OP knows what is a primitive pythagorean triple. Anyways, I'll edit my answer

Comment: You could note that the squares mod $3$ are $0$ and $1$. Also neither $a$ nor $b$ can be divisible by $3$ - say it were $a$ then consider $c^2-a^2=b^2$ to show $b$ is divisible by $3$. That leaves the case $1+1$.